# Segfault when iterating over a map<string, string> and drawing its contents using SDL_TTF

Tags: c++, sdl, debugging

I've written a class called DebugText.
The point of the class is to have a nice way of printing values of variables to the game screen.
The idea is to call SetDebugText() with the variables in question every time they change or, as is currently the case, every time the game's Update() is called.

The issue is that when iterating over the map that contains my variables and their latest updated values, I get segfaults.
See the comments in DrawDebugText() below, it specifies where the error happens.

I've tried splitting the calls to it->first and it->second into separate lines and found that the problem doesn't always happen when calling it->first. It alters between it->first and it->second.
I can't find a pattern.

It doesn't fail on every call to DrawDebugText() either.
It might fail on the third time DrawDebugText() is called, or it might fail on the fourth.

Class header:

```
#ifndef CLIENT_DEBUGTEXT_H
#define CLIENT_DEBUGTEXT_H

#include <Map>
#include <Math.h>
#include <sstream>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

#include "vector2.h"

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::map;
using std::pair;

using game::Vector2;

namespace game {

class DebugText {

  private:
  TTF_Font* debug_text_font;
  map<string, string>* debug_text_list;

  public:
  void SetDebugText(string var, bool value);
  void SetDebugText(string var, float value);
  void SetDebugText(string var, int value);
  void SetDebugText(string var, Vector2 value);
  void SetDebugText(string var, string value);
  int DrawDebugText(SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect*);
  void InitDebugText();
  void Clear();
};

}


#endif
```

Class source file:

```
#include "debugtext.h"


namespace game {

// Copypasta function for handling the toString conversion
template <class T>
inline string to_string (const T& t)
{
stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
ss << t;
return ss.str();
}

// Initializes SDL_TTF and sets its font
void DebugText::InitDebugText() {
  if(TTF_WasInit())
    TTF_Quit();

  TTF_Init();
  debug_text_font = TTF_OpenFont("LiberationSans-Regular.ttf", 16);
  TTF_SetFontStyle(debug_text_font, TTF_STYLE_NORMAL);
}


// Iterates over the current debug_text_list and draws every element on the screen.
// After drawing with SDL you need to get a rect specifying the area on the screen that was changed and tell SDL that this part of the screen needs to be updated. this is done in the game's Draw() function
// This function sets rects_to_update to the new list of rects provided by all of the surfaces and returns the number of rects in the list. These two parameters are used in Draw() when calling on SDL_UpdateRects(), which takes an SDL_Rect* and a list length
int DebugText::DrawDebugText(SDL_Surface* screen, SDL_Rect* rects_to_update) {
  if(debug_text_list == NULL)
    return 0;
  if(!TTF_WasInit())
    InitDebugText();

  rects_to_update = NULL;

  // Specifying the font color
  SDL_Color font_color = {0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; // r, g, b, unused

  int row_count = 0;
  string line;

  // The iterator variable
  map<string, string>::iterator it;

  // Gets the iterator and iterates over it
  for(it = debug_text_list->begin(); it != debug_text_list->end(); it++) {
    // Takes the first value (the name of the variable) and the second value (the value of the parameter in string form)


//---------THIS LINE GIVES ME SEGFAULTS-----
    line = it->first + ": " + it->second;  
//------------------------------------------


    // Creates a surface with the text on it that in turn can be rendered to the screen itself later
    SDL_Surface* debug_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(debug_text_font, line.c_str(), font_color);
    if(debug_surface == NULL) { // A standard check for errors
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s", TTF_GetError());
      return NULL;
    } else { // If SDL_TTF did its job right, then we now set a destination rect
        row_count++;
        SDL_Rect dstrect = {5, 5, 0, 0}; // x, y, w, h
        dstrect.x = 20;
        dstrect.y = 20*row_count;
        // Draws the surface with the text on it to the screen
        int res = SDL_BlitSurface(debug_surface,NULL,screen,&dstrect);
        if(res != 0) { //Just an error check
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
          return NULL;
        }
        // Creates a new rect to specify the area that needs to be updated with
        SDL_Rect* new_rect_to_update = (SDL_Rect*) malloc(sizeof(SDL_Rect));

        new_rect_to_update->h = debug_surface->h;
        new_rect_to_update->w = debug_surface->w;
        new_rect_to_update->x = dstrect.x;
        new_rect_to_update->y = dstrect.y;
        // Just freeing the surface since it isn't necessary anymore
        SDL_FreeSurface(debug_surface);

        // Creates a new list of rects with room for the new rect
        SDL_Rect* newtemp = (SDL_Rect*) malloc(row_count*sizeof(SDL_Rect));
        // Copies the data from the old list of rects to the new one
        memcpy(newtemp, rects_to_update, (row_count-1)*sizeof(SDL_Rect));
        // Adds the new rect to the new list
        newtemp[row_count-1] = *new_rect_to_update;
        // Frees the memory used by the old list
        free(rects_to_update);
        // And finally redirects the pointer to the old list to the new list
        rects_to_update = newtemp;
        newtemp = NULL;
    }
  }
  // When the entire map has been iterated over, return the number of lines that were drawn, ie. the number of rects in the returned rect list
  return row_count;

}


// The SetDebugText used by all the SetDebugText overloads
// Takes two strings, inserts them into the map as a pair
void DebugText::SetDebugText(string var, string value) {
  if (debug_text_list == NULL) {
    debug_text_list = new map<string, string>();
  }
  debug_text_list->erase(var);
  debug_text_list->insert(pair<string, string>(var, value));
}


// Writes the bool to a string and calls SetDebugText(string, string)
void DebugText::SetDebugText(string var, bool value) {
  string result;
  if (value)
    result = "True";
  else
    result = "False";

  SetDebugText(var, result);
}

// Does the same thing, but uses to_string() to convert the float
void DebugText::SetDebugText(string var, float value) {
  SetDebugText(var, to_string(value));
}

// Same as above, but int
void DebugText::SetDebugText(string var, int value) {
  SetDebugText(var, to_string(value));
}

// Vector2 is a struct of my own making. It contains the two float vars x and y
void DebugText::SetDebugText(string var, Vector2 value) {
  SetDebugText(var + ".x", to_string(value.x));
  SetDebugText(var + ".y", to_string(value.y));
}

// Empties the list. I don't actually use this in my code. Shame on me for writing something I don't use.
void DebugText::Clear() {
  if(debug_text_list != NULL)
    debug_text_list->clear();
}

}
```

Comment: Have you gone through it with a debugger and looking at what `it` is set to?

Comment: I've tried, but I keep getting errors in the watchlist when I try to look at it, *it or (*it)->first/second.

Comment: As this is a straight programming question, you'll probably get better answers on SO.  Migrating there.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you pre-increment instead of post-increment the it++ part of the for() loop?  for(it = debug_text_list->begin(); it != debug_text_list->end(); it++)

Answer (score 1):

I presume everything is running on a single thread? If not you need to use a mutex to make the code thread safe.

If it's not that then my guess would be that something is trashing memory. Assuming you're on Linux try using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find it.

Comment: It's all run in a single thread and I'm running it on Windows. I should be able to build it for Linux pretty easily since I only use SDL libraries, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: There are also tools for Windows available. For example take a look at http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/debug-heap-issues-with-full-page-heap-129771

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some kind of memory corruption.

One cause of bizarre STL memory-corruption errors I've run into before is when I accidentally built two libraries with different STL implementations and linked them together.  For example, in Visual Studio if you link debug and release libraries together, or libraries with different definitions of `_SECURE_SCL` or `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`, and then send STL containers across the library boundary, this sort of thing can happen.  I don't know whether your project has multiple library/executable parts, but if it does it's worth checking on this.

Beyond that, you'll probably just have to trawl through it in a debugger and look at the internals of the strings and STL containers to see if you can find out where/when the memory corruption is happening.  Try narrowing it down to a minimal test case, with as few items in the map as possible, and see if you can identify a specific field that's being corrupted; then use a data breakpoint to see when that field's being written to.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh right, I had completely forgotten about data breakpoints. Thanks for the advice! I'll do some more sophisticated debugging and see how it turns out.